# The html table is showing different cell width in each page

Tags: html, css, jsp, html-table

I was trying to list some data, the first table may contain first 10 data of the list remaining will show in the next table. I achieve this by looping the same table. But the table is showing different cell width in each page.

The first page shows table like this,

[image]

The second page shows the table like this,

[image]

The code i used is

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css" media="print">
@media print {
    html, body {
        color: black;
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh !important;
/*      overflow: hidden !important; */
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    @page {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
        size: A4 landscape;
        margin: 10;
    }
    .footer {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }
    input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio] {
        opacity: 1 !important;
    }
}
</style>

<style type="text/css">
page {
    background: white;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

page[size="A4"] {
    width: 21cm;
    height: 29.7cm;
}

page[size="A4"][layout="landscape"] {
    width: 29.7cm;
    height: 21cm;
}

.table-wtotbr {
    width: 100%;
}

.table-wtbr {
    width: 100%;
}

.table-wtotbr th, td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.table-wtbr th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.container-table {
    color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.checkbox {
  width:12px;
  height:12px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
    <%
        int rwln = Integer.parseInt(request.getAttribute("rwln").toString());
    int cnt = 0;
    int cntt = 0;
    int listlngth = 9;
    int begin = 0;

    int mnlpcnt = rwln / 10;
    double mlopct = (double) rwln / 10;
    %>


    <c:set value="<%=cntt%>" var="cntt"></c:set>
    <c:set value="<%=cnt%>" var="cnt"></c:set>
    <c:set value="<%=mnlpcnt%>" var="mnlpcnt"></c:set>
    <c:set value="<%=listlngth%>" var="listlngth"></c:set>
    <c:set value="<%=begin%>" var="begin"></c:set>



    <!-- getting current date -->
    <%
        Date dNow = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    String cdate = ft.format(dNow);
    %>
    <!-- /getting current date -->

    <jsp:useBean id="today" class="java.util.Date" />
    
    <c:forEach var="kk" begin="0" end="<%=mnlpcnt%>">
    
<page size="A4" layout="landscape">

    <div class="container-table">

        <table class="table-wtotbr">

            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">
                <img alt="logo" src="assets/images/logo.png" height="40px">
                    </td>
                <td style="text-align: center; width: 60%; font-size: 20px;">
                <b>Comapany</b>
                        </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="table-wtotbr">

            <tr height="10px">
                <td rowspan="2" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">Job
                    Travel Card</td>
                <td style="widtd: 10%;">JTC No:<%=request.getAttribute("jtcnum")%></td>
            </tr>

            <tr height="10px">
                <td>Date</td>
            </tr>


        </table>


        <table class="table-wtotbr">
            <tr height="10px">
                <td style="text-align: left; font-size: 8px;" colspan="2">Project
                    Number: <%=request.getAttribute("prjnno")%> </td>
                <td style="text-align: left; font-size: 8px;" colspan="2">Unit
                    No. / Tag No.:</td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="10px">
                <td style="text-align: left;" colspan="3">Area Number:</td>
                <td style="text-align: left;">Material Class: <%=request.getAttribute("mclass")%></td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="10px">
                <td style="text-align: left;">Drawing No: / ISO Number: <%=request.getAttribute("drwno")%></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;" widtd="25%">JC No: <%=request.getAttribute("miv")%></td>

                <td style="text-align: left;">Sheet No:</td>

                <td style="text-align: left;">Rev. No.:</td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="10px">
                <td style="text-align: left; font-size: 8px;">Item Description:</td>
                    <td style="text-align: left; font-size: 8px;" colspan="3">ITP
                    Stage Nos.:</td>
            </tr>
        </table>




        <!-- Fitup data table-sm  -->


        <table class="table-wtbr">

            <tr height="10px">
                <td rowspan="12" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
                    <span class="verticaltext"> Fabrication Assembly Fit-Up </span>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" rowspan="2">Weld/joint
                    No</td>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Material Spec Grade</td>
                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" rowspan="2">Size</td>
                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" rowspan="2">Thickness</td>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Heat/Plate/TestNo</td>
                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" rowspan="2">Welder
                    No. for tracking</td>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Fitup Result</td>
                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" rowspan="2">Date</td>
                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" rowspan="2" width="5%">Sign</td>
            </tr>




            <tr height="10px">
                <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 8px;" width="10%">Material
                    1</td>
                <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 8px;" width="10%">Material
                    2</td>

                <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 8px;" width="10%">Material
                    1</td>
                <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 8px;" width="10%">Material
                    2</td>
                <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 8px;">Accept</td>
                <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 8px;">Reject</td>
            </tr>




            <c:choose>

                <c:when test="${mnlpcnt <1 }">
                    <c:forEach var="jdata" items="${jtcdata}">
                        <tr height="10px" style="font-size: 12px;">
                            <td style="text-align: center;" width="7%">${jdata.getJointno()}</td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"  width="7%">${jdata.getItem1()}</td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"  width="7%">${jdata.getItem2()}</td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"  width="7%">${jdata.getDia()}</td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;" width="7%">${jdata.getThick()}</td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;" width="7%"></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;" width="7%"></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;" width="7%"></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;" width="7%"></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;" width="7%"></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;" width="7%"></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;" width="7%"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </c:when>

                <c:when test="${mnlpcnt >= 1 }">
                    <c:forEach var="qq" begin="${begin}" end="${listlngth}">
                        <tr height="10px" style="font-size: 12px;">
                            <td style="text-align: center;">${jtcdata[qq].getJointno()}</td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;">${jtcdata[qq].getItem1()}</td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;">${jtcdata[qq].getItem2()}</td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;">${jtcdata[qq].getDia()}</td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;">${jtcdata[qq].getThick()}</td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </c:when>

            </c:choose>







            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" style="font-size: 10px;">Name & Signature of
                    fabrication foreman</td>
                <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 10px;">Released to</td>

                <td colspan="1" style="font-size: 10px;">
                <div class="checkbox"></div>
                    QC/NDE/DIM.</td>
                <td colspan="3" style="font-size: 10px;"><div class="checkbox"></div>
                    Welding</td>

                <td colspan="4" style="font-size: 10px;"><div class="checkbox"></div>
                    Fabrication/Assembly</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="7" style="font-size: 10px;">Date</td>
                <td colspan="7" style="font-size: 10px;">Date</td>
            </tr>


        </table>
        <!-- welding data -->
        <table class="table-wtbr">

            <tr heigth="10px">
                <td rowspan="13" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
                    <span class="verticaltext"> Welding Details </span>
                </td>

                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" width="7%"
                    rowspan="3">Joint No</td>
                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" rowspan="3"
                    width="15%">WPS No.</td>
                <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center;">Welding Process</td>
                <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center;">Welder/Operation
                    No.</td>
                <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"
                    style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">Visual
                    Inspection</td>
                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" rowspan="3"
                    width="5%">Date</td>
                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" rowspan="3"
                    width="5%">Sign</td>


            </tr>

            <tr heigth="10px">

                <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center;">Passes</td>
                <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center;">Passes</td>

            </tr>





            <tr heigth="10px">

                <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 8px;" width="10%">Root/Hot</td>
                <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 8px;" width="10%">Fill</td>
                <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 8px;" width="10%">Cap</td>

                <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 8px;" width="10%">Root/Hot</td>
                <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 8px;" width="10%">Fill</td>
                <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 8px;" width="10%">Cap</td>

                <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 8px;" width="4%">Accept</td>
                <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 8px;" width="4%">Reject</td>


            </tr>




            <c:choose>

                <c:when test="${mnlpcnt <1 }">
                    <c:forEach var="jdata" items="${jtcdata}">

                        <tr height="10px" style="font-size: 12px;">
                            <td style="text-align: center;">${jdata.getJointno()}</td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
                        </tr>

                    </c:forEach>
                </c:when>

                <c:when test="${mnlpcnt >= 1 }">
                    <c:forEach var="pp" begin="${begin}" end="${listlngth}">

                        <tr height="10px" style="font-size: 12px;">
                            <td style="text-align: center;">${jtcdata[pp].getJointno()}</td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
                        </tr>

                    </c:forEach>
                </c:when>

            </c:choose>


            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" style="font-size: 10px;">Name & Signature of
                    fabrication foreman</td>
                <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 10px;">Released to</td>

                <td colspan="1" style="font-size: 10px;"><div class="checkbox"></div>
                    QC/NDE/DIM.</td>
                <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 10px;"><div class="checkbox"></div>
                    Welding</td>

                <td colspan="5" style="font-size: 10px;"><div class="checkbox"></div>
                    Fabrication/Assembly</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="14" style="font-size: 10px;">Name & Signature of
                    QC Personel</td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td colspan="7" style="font-size: 10px;">Date</td>
                <td colspan="7" style="font-size: 10px;">Date</td>
            </tr>
        </table>


        <div class="footer">

            <div style="float: left;">
                <!--
            <%=request.getAttribute("prjnno")%>-JTC-<%=request.getAttribute("jtcnum")%>-PIP-REV-01
             -->

                10636-JTC-276-PIP-REV-01
            </div>

            <div style="float: right;">
                <%=cdate%>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</page>


<%
begin = listlngth+1;
listlngth = listlngth+9;
%>
    <c:set value="<%=listlngth%>" var="listlngth"></c:set>
    <c:set value="<%=begin%>" var="begin"></c:set>
    
</c:forEach>




</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me to solving this issue.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I see some spelling mistake i.e :`heigth` should be `height` ? Is this your real code ?

Comment: Yup it is. Is that the problem?

Comment: Maybe change and see .Because when data are there it looks ok but without data its not showing proper height :)

Comment: @Swati it is not the issue. Didi you see in the first tabele ```Fabrication/Assembly``` takes colspan 2 but in the second table it takes 1.

Comment: @Swati the error was occurred because in the first table number of row was 10 and in the second table it was 9.